# Udacity Deep Learning Convolutional Neural Networks- TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been working on Udacity's course on deep learning- which I must add is great! I am very happy with the assignments so far. But there are two lines of code, that I am not quite understanding.

```
batch_size = 20
patch_size = 5
depth = 16
num_hidden = 64

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():

  # Input data.
  tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(
    tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size, image_size, num_channels))
  tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
  tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
  tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

  # Variables.
  layer1_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [patch_size, patch_size, num_channels, depth], stddev=0.1))
  layer1_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([depth]))
  layer2_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [patch_size, patch_size, depth, depth], stddev=0.1))
  ***********************************************************
  layer2_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[depth]))
  ***********************************************************
  layer3_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [image_size // 4 * image_size // 4 * depth, num_hidden], stddev=0.1))
  ***********************************************************
  layer3_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_hidden]))
  layer4_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [num_hidden, num_labels], stddev=0.1))
  layer4_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_labels]))

  # Model.
  def model(data):
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(data, layer1_weights, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + layer1_biases)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(hidden, layer2_weights, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + layer2_biases)
    shape = hidden.get_shape().as_list()
    reshape = tf.reshape(hidden, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, layer3_weights) + layer3_biases)
    return tf.matmul(hidden, layer4_weights) + layer4_biases

  # Training computation.
  logits = model(tf_train_dataset)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, tf_train_labels))

  # Optimizer.
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss)

  # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
  train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
  valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_valid_dataset))
  test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_test_dataset))
```

I have put asterisks around the parts of the code that I do not quite understand. First, I am not quite sure why the first set of biases between the input and convolutional layer are zeros, and then in the second layer they are then all ones.

Next, I do not understand the following line of code:

```
layer3_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
  [image_size // 4 * image_size // 4 * depth, num_hidden], stddev=0.1))
```

Specifically, I don't get why we have used `image_size // 4 * image_size // 4 * depth`, and I especially don't understand why we have used 4.

If you need more information then please let me know. This is taken from Udacity's deep learning course, where the notebooks are able to be cloned from GitHub.

Many thanks :)

Comment: they simply computed by hand, what is the size of the parameters space, this is a consequence of parameters used in convolution. It is reducing the size of the image (as you move your kernel around with some padding etc.), and in this case - it reduces the size four times. It is not a magical constant as such - just a consequence of parameters used in convolution layer before. They simply have to match, that's all.

Comment: Okay thank you @lejlot. Do you have any idea on why they have used different values for the initial biases?

Comment: I m pretty sure it will work with other initialization of biases as well. It looks completely arbitrary

Comment: I'm still on my learning path but could it be that the input layer does not have a bias? If that was the input layer in a shallow neural net no bias would be used.

Comment: no, initializing to zero is not removing bias. It is there, simply initialized the other way. Again - it should not matter, both will work

Answer (score 0):

To answer [image_size // 4 * image_size // 4 * depth] part:

The code applies convolution twice with SAME padding -

```
In each convolution the output image is half of input size (since stride = 2)
Therefore size of output after first 2 convolution layers is :
(image_size / 4) * (image_size / 4) * depth
```

Now next layer is fully connected layer so the input to this layer should be a flat image rather than 3D image, Hence, the weights of layer 3 are od dimensions:

```
((image_size / 4) * (image_size / 4) * depth), num_hidden
```